Export multiple pandas crosstabs into one html file with table of contents
I have created a pandas dataframe as follows:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ds = {'col1' : [1,1,2,3,4], 'col2' : [1,1,3,4,5], 'col3': [3,3,3,3,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)

The dataframe looks like this:
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     1     3
1     1     1     3
2     2     3     3
3     3     4     3
4     4     5     3

I have then produced two crosstabs as follows:
x1 = pd.crosstab(df['col1'], df['col2'], normalize='index').sort_index()
x2 = pd.crosstab(df['col1'], df['col3'], normalize='index').sort_index()

Which look like this:
print(x1)
print("")
print(x2)

col2    1    3    4    5
col1                    
1     1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2     0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3     0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
4     0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

col3    3
col1     
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0

I need to export those crosstabs results into one html file and that html file needs to have a table of contents at the top of the page containing the second element of the crosstab. So, the html would look something like this:
1. col2
2. col3

col2    1    3    4    5
col1                    
1     1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2     0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3     0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
4     0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0

col3    3
col1     
1     1.0
2     1.0
3     1.0
4     1.0


So this is not really a pandas question? More a HTML formatting/templating one, no?

I changed them a bit, should be more relevant ;)
